# Do the crew members in the plane have access to cargo area?

Tags: aircraft-design

I always thought that if there is fire ir something else happening in the cockpit, can the crew members go in cargo area to secure the place..

Comment: Some cargo area's have fire suppression systems installed, but I don't know of any passenger aircraft that has access to the cargo area from the cockpit. Cargo aircraft are usually accessible.

Comment: @RonBeyer -- I believe that some commuter aircraft have no C compartments, only As and Bs...